# css - align a div element to center

Tags: html, css

I have a div element `<div class='m-loading'>`. I'd like to align the element to center. My `css` is follows:

```
.m-loading {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: auto!important;
    margin-top: auto!important;
}
```

This doesn't work. The loading icon still appears on top-left.

[image: load]

Comment: `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` should do the trick here.

Comment: Also, making the parent element `display: flex`, and setting it with `justify-content: center; align-items: center` is almost always better.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen that didn't work for me. In order to center, I have to add arbitrary values like `margin-left: 350%; margin-top: 300%`. I am not sure if that work on different browsers / devices etc.